# Sphinx uses old module code

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I use Sphinx to document my code, which is a collection of Python modules. The autogenerated documentation that's made by scrubbing my source code is fine, but when I click on the "code" link that links directly to the HTML pages containing my package's sources that Sphinx generates, an older version of my code is shown.

I've tried deleting my Sphinx generated documentation, uninstalling the package from my own `site-packages` folder, and deleting everything in my `build` folder. I can find absolutely no files that match Sphinx's output - it's old, and I'm not sure where it's coming from. Does anybody know how to get Sphinx to put my new code in the documentation?

As I said, the autodocumentation works fine, so it's obviously parsing my code on some level. So why is the pure text different from the autodocumentation?

Comment: Another thing to try if the existing answers don't work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68017878/25050

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sphinx caches (pickles) parsed source files. The cache is usually located in a directory called **.doctrees** under the build directory. To ensure that your source files are reparsed, delete this directory.

See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-d.

Comment: This isn't clearing the cache for me.

Comment: Likewise, `rm -rf doc/build/docstrees/` does little to nothing for me. Sphinx's caching is obscenely overkill. It doesn't work as advertised, so I simply want *no* caching whatsoever – but I can't seem to get even that. Good uncached output >>>>>> bad cached output.

Answer (score 5):

**[Pass the poorly documented `-a` option to `sphinx-build`.](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-a)**

Doing so effectively disables all Sphinx caching by forcing Sphinx to rebuild all output documentation files (e.g., HTML in the `docs/build/` subdirectory), regardless of whether the underlying source input files have been directly modified or not. This is my preferred mode of operation when locally authoring Sphinx documentation, because I frankly do *not* trust Sphinx to safely cache what I expect it to. It never does.

For safety, I also:

- Prefer directly calling `sphinx-build` to indirectly invoking Sphinx through makefiles (e.g., `make html`).
- Pass `-W`, converting non-fatal warnings into fatal errors.
- Pass `--keep-going`, collecting *all* warnings before failing (rather than immediately failing on the first warning).
- Pass `-n`, enabling "nit-picky mode" generating one warning for each broken reference (e.g., interdocument or intrasection link).
- Pass `-j auto`, parallelizing the build process across *all* available CPU cores.

I have trust issues. I'm still shell-shocked from configuring Sphinx for ReadTheDocs three all-nighters ago. Now, I *always* locally run Sphinx via this command (wrapped in a Bash shell script or alias for convenience):

```sh
$ sphinx-build -M html doc/source/ doc/build/ -W -a -j auto -n --keep-going
```

That's just how we roll, Sphinx. It's Bash or bust.